# How does the first equation transform to the second one?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics

Well, this question may also require some physics knowledge of electric circuit to solve:

**The First equation:**
$R \times i_k + L \times \frac{di_k}{dt} = U_m \times \sin(\omega t + \varphi_{0u})$
where
 
$i_k$ is instantaneous value of short-circuit current.
$\varphi_{0u}$ is phase of power source voltage when short-circuit happened.

**The Second equation:**
$i_k = \frac{U_m}{Z}\sin(\omega t + \varphi_{0u}-\varphi)-\frac{U_m}{Z}\sin(\varphi_{0u}-\varphi)\times e^{-\frac{R}{L}\times t}$
where
$Z = R+jX$
$\varphi$ is the phase that current lags behind voltage.

Here is the equivalent circuit:
[image]

According to my book, the first equation can be transformed to the second one, I tried to proof that but I got stuck after a few steps.

Comment: You might do better posting this [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is simple ODE, you can solve it and get $$i_k(t) = c_1 e^{-(R t)/L} + 
 \dfrac{U}{(L^2 \omega^2 + R^2)}\left(R \sin(t \omega + ϕ_{0u}) - L  \omega \cos(t \omega + ϕ_{0u})\right)$$

Since $Z = R + jX = R + j \omega L $, so $|Z|^2 = R^2 + \omega^2L^2$

So you get, $$i_k(t) = c_1 e^{-(R t)/L} + 
 \dfrac{U}{|Z|^2}\left(R \sin(t \omega + ϕ_{0u}) - L  \omega \cos(t \omega + ϕ_{0u})\right)  $$

Let $\cos \phi = \dfrac{R}{|Z|}$ and $\sin \phi = \dfrac{X}{|Z|}$

$$i_k(t) = c_1 e^{-(R t)/L} + 
 \dfrac{U}{|Z|}\left( \sin(t \omega + ϕ_{0u} - \phi) \right)  $$

At $t = 0$.

$$i_k(0) = c_1 + \dfrac{U}{|Z|}\sin( ϕ_{0u} - \phi)$$

I think at $t = 0$ current should be zero, so

$$c_1 = - \dfrac{U}{|Z|}\sin( ϕ_{0u} - \phi)$$.

$$i_k(t) =  
 \dfrac{U}{|Z|}\left( \sin(t \omega + ϕ_{0u} - \phi) \right) - \dfrac{U}{|Z|}\sin( ϕ_{0u} - \phi) e^{-(R t)/L} $$